# uh oh - app stopped unexpectedly

Tags: java, android

[image]

I ran my app in the emulator. Where do I even begin?

First line from LogCat:

11-28 23:41:03.912: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(391): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: Type `adb logcat` in the terminal and post the stack trace.

Comment: Do you know basic Java Programming and Debugging techniques? What are you using to develop?

Comment: cfei thanks for your help. can you direct me how to that? thank you

Comment: Can you provide more details?  Did your application launch at all before you received this dialog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using eclipse then open the debug view.  One of the windows is logcat.  Watch that window and when the app crashes there will be a stream of red text (or click the circled e in the filters above the window).  The first line will be the actual reason for the crash, more useful will be a line about halfway down that starts with 'caused by ..'.

Figure out what caused it and then do some research to find a solution.  Sometimes it is as easy as 'caused by activity not in manifest file. Did you add activity to the manifest?' and then other times it takes some digging.

You can also copy and paste the logcat code from that window and add to your question for more help.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is happening before your app launches, you should make sure your `AndroidManifest.xml` is setup correctly.  Make sure your activity is declared, and the `android:name` attribute either contains the entire package, or your start your classname with a .  For example, it might be:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"...
```

(where MyActivity is the name of the Activity class being launched)
or

```
 <activity android:name="com.levinotik.nycourts.MyActivity"...
```